# UITableView parallax header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallax

I want this type of UI

[image]

Please see above image I want this type of UI.

Any custom controller available ?

But image view position fix not scrolling. When scroll uitableview only table rows above image view image position fixed.

Thanks all

Comment: and what you have tried so far ? can you please post your code ?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with [CSSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout).